# ajax form request not working with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The problem is that it does not call ajax request when url is rewriten with mod_rewrite.

But when I remove the last slash from the link it works.

**Example link:**

*With this urls it works*

`http://localhost/project/user-list`

`http://localhost/project/user_list.php`

**But when url look like this (added slash to end) ajax request not working.**

`http://localhost/project/user-list/`

Here is my **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule     ^user-list/?$               user_list.php                 [QSA,L]
```

**Calls for .js files look like this:**

`<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/js/file.js"></script>`

**BASE_URL** defined with:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/project');
```

I using plugin **[jquery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)** created by **[malsum](https://github.com/malsup)**.

Example of form:

jQuery:

```
$('#form_example').ajaxForm({ 
    success: function(result) {     
        alert("success");
    }       
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form_example" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mnencia Hi, thanks. Have I broken any rule by raising this issue? If I did, I apologize, just tell me where the error if any..

Comment: Not really. Only I find that your question is not clear enough, so I gave you some useful links on how to answer a good question.

Comment: Try adding **<base href="/">** inbetween <head> and </head> of your doc.

Comment: @Starkeen Nothing happens, it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/project` when the page is `/user-list.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/project/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/project/user-list/` the base suddenly becomes `/project/user-list` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/project/">
```

Comment: I assumed that was the problem, but Nissan has a solution. Thank you very much for this, even just now when you're in a commentary written for the `<base href="/">` I changed the `<base href="/project/admin/">` and now works perfectly. Thanks again, increased I vote on this post.